# Creating an additional related model with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've started to implement a new project using Devise, which is pretty fantastic for handling users. However, when a user signs up, they're not just creating a `User` model, but also need to create a related `Account` model that represents the company. Additional users will also `belongs_to` this `Account` model.

I can't seem to find a hook for this in Devise, though it seems like a pretty common pattern. What's the best practice for this?

I should also mention that there are a couple of fields for the `Account` that need to be provided on the sign_up form, so just something like this in the `User` model:

```
  after_create :make_sure_account_exists  
  def make_sure_account_exists
    if self.account.nil?
      @account = self.create_account({ :company_name => '???' })
  end
```

.. as I'm not sure how to get the company name.