# How do I use nested attributes with the devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the same issue as [Creating an additional related model with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027555/creating-an-additional-related-model-with-devise) (which has no answer).

I have overridden the devise view for creating a new user and added a company name, I have changed the model to use accepts_nested_attributes_for

There are no errors, but it is **not adding the nested record** and I don't have a controller where I can modify the request.

I have the following (shortened to make it readable):

**routes.rb**

```
map.devise_for :users
map.resources :users, :has_many => :companies
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :companies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
devise :registerable ... etc
```

**company.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**new.html.erb**

```
...
<% form_for resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
...
  <% f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
    <p><%= company_form.label :name %></p>
    <p><%= company_form.text_field :name %></p>
  <% end %>
...
```

UPDATE:
I didn't add :company to the attr_accessible list in the User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be trying to mass assign some protected variable, OR you might not be saving a valid record.  Check to make sure that the record is actually saving to the db.

Comment: Yep - it was a mass-assign, I was not defining :company in the attr_accessible in user.rb

new problem now - purely a devise issue

Answer (score 16):

You can add the following method to the User model:

**user.rb**

```
def with_company
  self.companies.build
  self
end
```

And modify the view:

**new.html.erb**

```
...
<% form_for [resource_name, resource.with_company], :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
...
  <% f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
  ...
  <% end %>
```

This way, you'll have the nested form to add **one** company to the user.
To dynamically add multiple companies to the user, check the [Railcast #197 by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).
Make sure you are passing the pair of resources as an array, otherwide you will get an error like this: "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)".

Comment: I don't know how good this solution fits in the MVC Modell but it works.

Comment: You should only build it once, or it gets built each time you submit the form <line break> `self.companies.build if self.companies.empty?`

Comment: why pass in resource_name, shouldn't below works too?
<% form_for resource.with_company,  ...

Comment: For anyone using this solution, both @meleyal and @GeorgeW are correct. However, watch out for ActiveRecord lazy loading, use `self.companies.build if self.companies(true).empty?`, otherwise `empty?` might return true even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I realised this is a very old thread, but since I found a better solution, hence the reply.

Just change the new.html.erb as follows,

```
<% form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,:url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
    ...
    <% prefix = "user[company_attributes]"%>
    <% fields_for prefix, @user.company do |company_form| %>
    ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way when @user.save gets invoked, it would run company.save too with all the validations you may have in company model.

I don't have whole lot of RoR experience, but I think this is a better solution. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what `fields_for :company do |company_form|` does. So this is not a better solution.