# Override devise registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have added a field to the sign-up form that is based on a different model, see [How do I use nested attributes with the devise model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544265/how-do-i-use-nested-attributes-with-the-devise-model) for the gory details. This part is working fine.

The problem now is when I save, it is failing in the create action of the registrations controller that is supplied by devise with an `Activerecord::UnknownAttributeError` on this field (company).

I am assuming I need to override the registrations controller, or is there a better/easier way I should be approaching this?

Comment: I actually wrote a whole blog post on this https://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 363, accepted):

In your form are you passing in any other attributes, via mass assignment that don't belong to your user model, or any of the nested models?

If so, I believe the ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError is triggered in this instance.

Otherwise, I think you can just create your own controller, by generating something like this:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

And then tell devise to use that controller instead of the default with:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Comment: But how do you make sure devise looks in the devise dir for the views? I'm trying this but devise methods like "sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)" are looking in views for the template.

Comment: If you want to customise your devise views, you just need to generate them first and devise will check your views folder before loading the views from the gem. In Rails 3 it's: `rails generate devise:views` and in Rails 2 (i think) it's: `script/generate devise:views`

Comment: the above hack doesn't work with devise 1.0.8 which is the version works for rails 2.

Comment: If you override a Devise controller like this, make sure you copy all views from app/views/devise/registrations to app/views/registrations/ (change for whichever controller you're overriding).

Comment: Alternatively you can leave your devise views where they are and add `paths.app.views << "app/views/devise"` in your `config/application.rb`.

Comment: THis doesn't seem to work in devise 1.4.2. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659555/how-to-set-up-devise-routes-to-accept-invitation-token-in-url-on-sign-up/6660047#6660047

Comment: That's the approach I'm taking, but I don't have a clue what to put in there since Devise uses this `resource` stuff. Doesn't seem to be congruent with my already-working create method in my own controller. My post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746998/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-for-creating-a-has-many-nested-model-with

Comment: also note that recent versions of devise allow to use `super` with a block that yields the resource.

Comment: so if i don't create an action in the controller subclass, the parent action  is automatically used instead? Is that how it works?

Comment: I had to `devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations' }`

Comment: Do you know how to access the submitted "user" resource in create controller?

Answer (score 67):

A better and more organized way of overriding Devise controllers and views using namespaces:

Create the following folders:

```
app/controllers/my_devise
app/views/my_devise
```

Put all controllers that you want to override into app/controllers/my_devise and add `MyDevise` namespace to controller class names. `Registrations` example:

```
# app/controllers/my_devise/registrations_controller.rb
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  ...

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
  end

  ...    

end
```

Change your routes accordingly:

```
devise_for :users,
           :controllers  => {
             :registrations => 'my_devise/registrations',
             # ...
           }
```

Copy all required views into `app/views/my_devise` from Devise gem folder or use `rails generate devise:views`, delete the views you are not overriding and rename `devise` folder to `my_devise`.

This way you will have everything neatly organized in two folders.

Comment: This is similar to the approach I'm taking, but I don't know what custom logic to put in the `create` method of Devise's I overwrote. My scaffold-created controller that I modified works great, but how do you make it work with Devise's `resource` business?

Comment: @Vincent thank you - if i want to override just one method, do i write just the method i want to override - and will everything else just work as normal? Your assistance much appreciated

Comment: `MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` creates a circular dependency error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 34):

I believe there is a better solution than rewrite the RegistrationsController. I did exactly the same thing (I just have Organization instead of Company).

If you set properly your nested form, at model and view level, everything works like a charm.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :owned_organizations, :class_name => 'Organization', :foreign_key => :owner_id

  has_many :organization_memberships
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_memberships

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :username, :owned_organizations_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owned_organizations
  ...
end
```

My Organization Model:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :organization_memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :organization_memberships
  has_many :contracts

  attr_accessor :plan_name

  after_create :set_owner_membership, :set_contract
  ...
end
```

My view : 'devise/registrations/new.html.erb'

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% resource.owned_organizations.build if resource.owned_organizations.empty? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <%= f.fields_for :owned_organizations do |organization_form| %>

    <p><%= organization_form.label :name %><br />
      <%= organization_form.text_field :name %></p>

    <p><%= organization_form.label :subdomain %><br />
      <%= organization_form.text_field :subdomain %></p>

    <%= organization_form.hidden_field :plan_name, :value => params[:plan] %>

  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Moving the build logic from the view to the model would be cleaner, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544265#3764837

Comment: I generated the devise controllers and now have controller action create triggered when user clicks Sign up. Is there a way(like overriding / some example code) I can use Devise to encrypt the password and do backend checks of the password and other fields? and saving it to the model database?

Comment: How are you able to access the local variable `resource` in the view instead of a class instance variable `@resource`?

Answer (score 17):

Very simple methods
Just go to the terminal and the type following

```
rails g devise:controllers users //This will create devise controllers in controllers/users folder
```

Next to use custom views

```
rails g devise:views users //This will create devise views in views/users folder
```

now in your route.rb file

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
           :sessions => "users/sessions",
           :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

You can add other controllers too. This will make devise to use controllers in users folder and views in users folder.

Now you can customize your views as your desire and add your logic to controllers in controllers/users folder. 
Enjoy !

Answer (score 14):

You can generate views and controllers for devise customization.

Use

```
rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations
```

and

```
rails g devise:views
```

It will copy particular controllers and views from gem to your application.

Next, tell the router to use this controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I was trying to customize the params that devise permits on signup.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35827502/374873) to create the custom controller, and then tried permitting the attribute, `timezone` like so:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:timezone])
end
```

It didn't work until I **ALSO** uncommented the line at the top of the generated controller:

`before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]`