# Update the User controller of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Rails 3.0.3 and devise 1.1.5 ([devise on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise))

My `User` model `belongs_to` the `Company` model with the foreign_key `company_id`

When a new User is created (at Sign Up), I need to associate him with a new company.

So, basically, I need to put the following code somewhere

```
@user.company = Company.new
@user.save
```

The user controller is manage in the devise dependency, is it possible to generate the controller used by devise in my app/controllers directory

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a company has to be associated for each new user, I put this code in the `User` model in a `before_create` filter.

Comment: should a 'company has_one user' or the other way around? eg should the user model get a company_id or the other way around?

Comment: A Company has many users, the Users table has a company_id fk

Comment: :before_create "self.create_company"

Answer (score 1):

You can customize devise controllers - just copy the default ones from devise/app/controllers into your own application directory and add your own code to them.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller

Comment: in a rails 3 project... where is the devise/app/controllers directory?

Comment: jpqynn, Had the same question. If you are using RVM, it would be in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset_name/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/controllers/