# How to reroute standard rest actions to devise controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller

I have been building devise into a small Rails app.  It's a pretty standard setup but one wrinkle is that the default authentication rules need to be changed for this project.  Non-idempotent registration actions must all be restricted to only authenticated users.

To do this, I've written a custom registrations controller and linked it up in the routing.  All the custom controller really has to do is alter the filtering requirements.  Based on the Rails controller filtering [documentation](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html), I got this working with a minimum of effort.

But by itself that only applies to devise-specific actions like /users/sign_up or /users/edit.  I would also like to wire in the standard Rails actions (/users/new, /users/1/edit, etc) to the custom controller.  I can get the action to instantiate the controller -- leading the horse to water so to speak -- but when the action is new instead of sign_up, it crashes out during the filtering.

The problem appears to be that resource_name yields nil when the action is 'new', but is fine when it's 'sign_up'.  I don't understand why devise cares or where the distinction is represented in code.  I've looked at other questions like [Update the User controller of devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907376/update-the-user-controller-of-devise) and [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) and [Custom Devise controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655114/custom-devise-controller) but they don't get into this issue.

The specific error I am getting is

> **NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#new**
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

and the top of the trace is

> devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:22:in
>   `resource_name' app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:104:in`
>   authenticate_scope!'

It is apparently happening the first time devise_mapping is referenced.  But as per the above stackoverflow question I have also explicitly provided helpers for devise_mapping, and they don't even get called.

Can anyone explain or help me figure out where to look further?

from routes.rb:

```
Fs::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' } 
  resources :users, :except => [:index, :show], :controller => 'registrations'
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]
```

[...]

rake routes reports:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)             registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                    registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)            registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)               registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                    registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                    registrations#destroy
                   users POST   /users(.:format)                    registrations#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                registrations#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           registrations#edit
                    user PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                registrations#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                registrations#destroy
                         GET    /users(.:format)                    users#index
                         GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
```

my registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :except => [:index, :show]
  skip_filter :require_no_authentication
end
```

my users_helper.rb:

```
module UsersHelper
  # used by devise
  def resource_name
    :user 
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

using:

Rails 3.2.6

Ruby 1.9.3

devise 2.1.2

Update: pasted in the correct trace output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So one solution appears to be to add

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/new' => 'registrations#new'
  end
```

into routes.rb.  This may not be the best answer but it works.