# Overriding the controller in Engines (specifically, in Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I want to remove Devise's set_flash_message on signin/signout, so I created
my own sessions_controller, copied verbatim from devise's. I copied the view over to app/views/sessions, and changed the route. Now, when I sign in, it redirects me back to the sign in page. The rails log shows

```
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
```

which doesn't show up when I use the built-in session controller. Any ideas?

I can work around this without overriding the controller, but I suspect I'll want to do that anyway at some point and hit this same problem. Jose has no idea. How can I troubleshoot this?

Jay Levitt

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb: Same as /Users/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/devise-1.2.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb.

config/routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => :sessions }
  ...
```

rails output using my copy of controller:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-07 16:15:54
-0400
  Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o8JIe+jGu
+xiuuIbAZc6kg6aD6TKk86rKBydeFxLH40=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"jlev...@tiptap.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  PK and serial sequence (1.7ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"badges_users"'::regclass

  PK and custom sequence (0.8ms)   SELECT attr.attname,
 CASE
 WHEN split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2) ~ '.' THEN
 substr(split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2),
 strpos(split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2), '.')+1)
 ELSE split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2)
 END
 FROM pg_class t
 JOIN pg_attribute attr ON (t.oid = attrelid)
 JOIN pg_attrdef def ON (adrelid = attrelid AND adnum = attnum)
 JOIN pg_constraint cons ON (conrelid = adrelid AND adnum = conkey[1])
 WHERE t.oid = '"badges_users"'::regclass
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND def.adsrc ~* 'nextval'
Completed   in 101ms
  Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o8JIe+jGu
+xiuuIbAZc6kg6aD6TKk86rKBydeFxLH40=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"jlev...@tiptap.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  SQL (0.9ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid,
a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/devise/sessions (9.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 162ms (Views: 13.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

rails output using the built-in controller:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-08 10:41:35 -0400
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m3gKBQM8We9oHvsLjkPA8O/wQEJeZibRtY0tDgqZHxk=", "user"=>{"email"=>"jlevitt@tiptap.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  PK and serial sequence (1.8ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"badges_users"'::regclass
  PK and custom sequence (0.7ms)   SELECT attr.attname,
 CASE
 WHEN split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2) ~ '.' THEN
 substr(split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2),
 strpos(split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2), '.')+1)
 ELSE split_part(def.adsrc, '''', 2)
 END
 FROM pg_class t
 JOIN pg_attribute attr ON (t.oid = attrelid)
 JOIN pg_attrdef def ON (adrelid = attrelid AND adnum = attnum)
 JOIN pg_constraint cons ON (conrelid = adrelid AND adnum = conkey[1])
 WHERE t.oid = '"badges_users"'::regclass
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND def.adsrc ~* 'nextval'

  SQL (0.7ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jlevitt@tiptap.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-04-08 13:12:42.161090', "current_sign_in_at" = '2011-04-08 14:41:35.486567', "sign_in_count" = 17, "updated_at" = '2011-04-08 14:41:35.487136' WHERE "users"."id" = 6
  SQL (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 302ms
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to customize the messages that devise uses, just edit the devise.en.yml file

**config/locales/devise.en.yml**

```
en:
  ...
  devise:
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Signed in successfully.'
      signed_out: 'Signed out successfully.'
```

Comment: Correct for the flash notifications, but I'm looking for the right answer for controller overriding in general; I'll want to do it for other reasons.

Comment: @jay: maybe edit your answer for why you want to override the sessions controller? Otherwise just check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller