# devise sign up automatically signs in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise

when i sign up a user, but don't have confirmable setup just yet (i.e. will be in the future but commented out for now), does it automatically sign in the user?

i need sign_up to just sign_up the user, but not sign him in, it needs to redirect to the login page, how do i get sign up to not log the user in?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of copy pasting code and replacing one line (which could be harder to maintain), just override the after_sign_up_path_for(resource), so it uses the after_sign_in_path_for(resource) instead:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to have different paths depending on the request type ? (Html, JS, JSON, etc.) ?

Comment: No need, devise's registration controller uses this path within `respond_with` (e.g. `respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`, so that will take care of the request type for you. Devise should respond to JSON by default, I'm not sure about JS.

Answer (score 5):

You need allow unconfirmed user to access at least one day.

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.days
```

Answer (score 0):

[Override the RegistrationsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) and then override the create action. Then [replace this line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L19) in your new create action. Don't forget to use the rest of the code from the original create action.

Comment: if i enable confirmable, i'm assuming it won't automatically sign in the user until he's confirmed?  is that correct?

Comment: yes, then the login would occur when the user clicks on the confirmation link in the email

Comment: Not necessarily, confirmable will allow the user to login if allow_unconfirmed_access_for is set. (See devise.rb)

For example, you could:

    config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.days