# Creating a new devise resource, while signed in as a different devise resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two Devise models: `User` and `Vendor`. I don't want Vendors signing up themselves, so Admin users (controlled by boolean field on users table) should be able to create new Vendors while signed in. Currently when I try this while signed_in, I can't access the `vendors_sign_up_path`. I get this error from the server:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

So apparently to access this page you can't be authenticated? Seems to make sense for most situations, but how can I override this? I've created a custom devise vendors/registrations controller like so to prevent auto-sign-in after sign-up (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545306/dont-allow-sign-in-after-sign-up-in-devise)) :

```
class Vendors::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
    super
end


protected

def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    true
end

end
```

It seems like I need to override something else in the registrations controller to get this done? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just create a vendors/new page/action and create vendors through a regular form? You could even reuse the Devise form...

Comment: Ah that's a good idea I think. Will doing so include all of Devise's modules? I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your routes?

```
resources :admins do
  resources :vendors
end
devise_scope :vendor do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Anyway, my advise would be to use roles here:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  def has_role?(role_sym)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym }
  end
end


#role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments  
end

#assignment.rb
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

This way vendors can be registered as users and an admin should be able to change the role as vendor later.

Comment: Hmmm...I have `Vendor` and `User` as different models for some important relational reasons, plus they have very few attributes in common. I don't really want to lump them into one User class, as the complexity of the relationships will only grow in the future. I don't have that `routes` code block. What exactly does that do?

Comment: First route gives the ability to admins to create vendors.
Second route creates a Devise sign in path for vendors.