# How do I customize the controller for registration in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, devise

I need to add some simple methods and actions when a new user registers through Devise.

I want to apply a notify method which will send an email to me.

I want to use acts_as_network to pass a session value and connect the new register to the person who invited them.

How do I customize, I looked at the docs, but I'm not entirely clear what I need to do....thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller

Comment: @feelway, no I haven't, but it looks promising...I guess "super" means it is inheriting from the Devise controller?

Comment: Yes. Super will executes the code from the inherited method.

Comment: @feelnoway, this looks like it should be the right answer, thanks....can you put as answer so I can accept (and also if I have more questions for you post them?)

Answer (score 15):

This is what I'm doing to override the Devise Registrations controller. I needed to catch an exception that can potentially be thrown when registering a new User but you can apply the same technique to customize your registration logic.

**app/controllers/devise/custom/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super # no customization, simply call the devise implementation
  end

  def create
    begin
      super # this calls Devise::RegistrationsController#create
    rescue MyApp::Error => e
      e.errors.each { |error| resource.errors.add :base, error }
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end

  def update
    super # no customization, simply call the devise implementation 
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Note that I created a new `devise/custom` directory structure under `app/controllers` where I placed my customized version of the RegistrationsController. As a result you'll need to move your devise registrations views from `app/views/devise/registrations` to `app/views/devise/custom/registrations`.

Also note that overriding the devise Registrations controller allows you to customize a few other things such as where to redirect a user after a successful registration. This is done by overriding the `after_sign_up_path_for` and/or `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` methods.

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users,
             :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/custom/registrations" }
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) may offer additional information you might be interested in.