# Devise: Overriding create action in Registrations Controller for Recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, recaptcha

I'm trying to override the create method from the Registrations Controller in [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.0) to include Recaptcha verification (as seen [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash[:alert] = "Bad words."
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end

end
```

Also changed my routes.rb accordingly:

```
  map.devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :path_names => {
    :sign_up => 'signup',
    :sign_in => 'login',
    :sign_out => 'logout'
  }
```

When trying to visit the new registration page (with new path name: http://localhost:3000/users/signup) this errors shows up:

```
LoadError in RegistrationsController#new

Expected /home/benoror/project/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb to define RegistrationsController
```

[FULL ERROR TRACE](http://pastebin.com/WsB3UaWK)

Any help appreciated.

**BTW**, I'm using Devise 1.0.11 and Rails 2.3.10, thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us the path of the RegistrationsController that you wrote? Also, when you run `rake routes | grep registrations` does the output look right?

Comment: The path is actually app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb . And the routes seem fine: http://pastebin.com/qnqaVLEt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your controller in a Users module? If so, you will need

```
class Users::RegistrationsController
```

and

```
{:registrations => "users/registrations"}
```

**Edit:** [According to José Valim](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/673d01d07ea0d57f), custom controllers don't work prior to Devise 1.1. No reason to be developing on < Rails 3 imho. Sorry I missed that in the original post.

Comment: Nop, I'm not managing it under a sub-module, I'm following Devise classic installation instructions.

Comment: But, it calls directly the create method from Devise controller, doesn't seem to call the override method :(

Comment: In my experience, the convention for customizing the controllers is to `rails g controller Users::Registrations` which places the file in app/controllers/users/. I don't know enough about devise to know why that might be necessary.

Comment: I'm using Devise 1.0.11 and Rails 2.3.10, and even that way, it just ignores the overriden method

Comment: Wow, that's bad news. Rails 3 migration is planned but it would requiere much time, we wanted to stick to 2.3 as long as we could.