# How do you access Devise controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Are controllers in devise automatically generated? How do you access them?

I know for views you do
`rails generate devise_views`.

Comment: Repost of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller

Comment: The answer to this question depends on which version of Rails you are using. If using Rails 4 in 2016, then the correct answer is not marked correct.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Devise uses internal controllers, which you can access and subclass in your own code. They are under the `Devise` module. For example, to extend the `RegistrationsController`:

```
class MembershipsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
end
```

Then all you have to do is configure Devise's routes to use your controller instead:

```
devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => 'memberships' }
```

Comment: Is there a way to simply view the devise controllers like you would with the views? In my case, I would like to add code to the devise registrations controller instead of re-writing it; and I'm not sure where and how I want to add to it without seeing what is in their first. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mmichael, you can find the source code of Devise's controllers [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise). By reading the source you can understand what each method is doing, and then figure out the best way to implement your features.

Answer (score 61):

Under the assumption that you want to see these controllers in order to modify or override them, Devise now provides a simple generator which recreates their controllers in your app to make this easy.  As per [the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) (which will be most up-to-date):

**1) Create your custom controllers using the generator which requires a scope:**

*console*

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

If you specify `users` as the scope, controllers will be created in `app/controllers/users/`. And the sessions controller will look like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end
  ...
end
```

---

**2) Tell the router to use this controller:**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

---

**3) Copy the views from `devise/sessions` to `users/sessions`. Since the controller was changed, it won't use the default views located in `devise/sessions`.**

---

**4) Finally, change or extend the desired controller actions.**

You can completely override a controller action:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    # custom sign-in code
  end
end
```

Or you can simply add new behaviour to it:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      BackgroundWorker.trigger(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

This is useful for triggering background jobs or logging events during certain actions.

Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in was successful or unsuccessful. Devise expects your application to call `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:alert]` as appropriate. Do not print the entire flash hash, print only specific keys. In some circumstances, Devise adds a `:timedout` key to the flash hash, which is not meant for display. Remove this key from the hash if you intend to print the entire hash.

Comment: This is the best way to do it now and should be the top answer.

Comment: I didn't have to change the location of my views, I'm assuming rails is just looking for them in the Devise directory because it be smart, yo.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this should now be marked as the correct answer in 2016.

Comment: Also run bundle update devise to make sure your version supports it. Also You do not need to change location of views.

Comment: This is still only going to show a controller where the methods just contain `super`... It helps with overriding but you still have to copy code from the original controller if you don't want to rewrite all of it. Is there an option to actually show the whole controller? In my example I just want to do a check for the environment mode and if it's in development skip the confirmation mail.
ps: found awesome answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169179/5909738

Comment: here is where you do the `show` , `edit` and `update`?

Answer (score 11):

`$ rails generate devise:controllers SCOPE [options]`

Options:
  -c, [--controllers=one two three]

## Select specific controllers to generate (confirmations, passwords, registrations, sessions, unlocks, omniauth_callbacks)

Use -c to specify which controller you want to overwrite.
If you do not specify a controller, all devise controllers will be created.
For example:

rails generate devise:controllers users -c=sessions

This will create a controller class at app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb like this:

```
 class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    content...
 end
```

Answer (score 10):

**Below one is for Rails 5**

Generate rails devise controllers using the following command:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

if you modified the above generated controllers, add the following line to the `routes.rb`,

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations:'user/registrations'}
```

Your modifications will take effect once you restart the rails server

Comment: You will also need to move views from `app/views/devise/CONTROLLER/...` -> `app/views/users/CONTROLLER/...` when you do this so that your new controller can find them.

Answer (score 1):

#### To define custom controller behavior,

see @ErikTrautman's answer.

#### But if you're trying to understand what Devise is doing under the hood,

you must inspect the source (specifically, in the project root's `app/` directory). @MatheusMoreira provides a link to the source on GitHub, but if you'd rather browse it locally in your own text editor, you can find the install location of the Devise gem with `gem which devise`.

For instance, to see `Devise::SessionsController`:

```
$ vim $(gem which devise | sed 's|\(.*\)\(/.*\)\{2\}|\1|')/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
```

(Or, you could just clone the git repo and poke around that way.)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
$ cd devise
$ vim app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
```