# Devise - Skipping user confirmation in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

How do you skip user confirmation in development in devise.

I have set up the production environment to send emails with SendGrid, but now I have done that it won't let me log in.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create User in console:

```
user = User.create( 
  :first_name            => 'admin', 
  :last_name             => 'admin', 
  :email                 => 'foo...@email.com', 
  :password              => 'password1', 
  :password_confirmation => 'password1' 
).skip_confirmation! 
 # Devise :doc:
 # If you don't want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code
 # to be generated, call skip_confirmation!
```

or in model:

```
 after_create :skip_conf!

  def skip_conf!
    self.confirm! if Rails.env.development?
  end
```

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Clean and easy ;)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had to use just `.confirm` not `.confirm!`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
User.new(email: 'xx@xx.xx', password: '12345678').confirm!
```

BTW, you can skip :password_confirmation at all, because #confirm! skips validation if record does not persisted yet.