# How to save Facebook UID in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, devise

I am using Devise and I have it so a User clicks `"log in with facebook"`. Once they confirm this, it then takes them to the registration url `"http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_up"`.

In here I then populate the name and email fields with the ones I got from Facebook. They now just have to pick a password to sign up. I also want to save the user's Facebook UID and their Facebook url.

How do I pass this into my User model once the user clicks on the sign up button? (I updated my model to include these extra fields).

Edit: I currently also store their Facebook hash data in a session that I got from Ominauth so that I can retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the auth hash provided by Omniauth you should be able to retrieve the user information.

For example the hash has a structure that looks like [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema).
You can pull the user information like this:

```
facebook_uid = user_auth.uid
facebook_url = user.user_info.urls
```

Comment: I was able to get the id and url but now how do I put this in with the user once they click sign up. I want to save it with their account.

Comment: You say you have access to the hash right? Override the devise controllers new method to store the data values you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller

Comment: Please checkout this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2