# Problem overriding Devise::RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've read similar articles like [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) , but Devise in my app doesn't override correctly.

I am using Devise 1.4.2 and Rails 3.0.9 on my Mac (OSX 10.6.8).

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    debugger
  end

  def create
    debugger
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Then I started my local server with --debugger option (ruby-debug19 is installed) and when access to /users/sign_up, debugger doesn't trigger.

```
rails server --debugger

Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-11 21:21:46 +0900
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (3.8ms)
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (20.4ms)
```

Updated: I checked my routings with "rake routes", but the routing for sign_up still remains as below.

```
user_registration POST /users(.:format) {
    :action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
new_user_registration GET /users/sign_up(.:format) {
    :action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
```

I want :controller to point "registrations" (without "devise/") when POST.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your filename is `registration_controllers.rb` it should be `registration_controller.rb`

Comment: Lloyd, thank you for pointing out, but it was my typo when posting to stackoverflow. I fixed it.

Comment: registrations_controller.rb might be even more appropriate, especially if you are calling it "registrations" in routes.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes.rb file,

You can amend your devise routes in the following way:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```