# How to write controller tests when you override devise registration controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I wish to override the `Devise::RegistrationsController` to implement some custom functionalality. To do this, I've created a new `RegistrationsController` like so:

```
# /app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end
end
```

and set up my routes like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

and tried to test it like this:

```
describe RegistrationsController do
  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

but that gives me an error:

```
 1) RegistrationsController GET 'new' should be successful
 Failure/Error: get :new
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/sign_up".
   Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

       devise_scope :user do
         match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
       end
 # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is that Devise is unable to map routes from the test back to the original controller. That means that while your app actually works fine if you open it in the browser, your controller tests will still fail.

The solution is to add the devise mapping to the request before each test like so:

```
before :each do
  request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Comment: What file do you add this to - I can't figure it out, thanks.

Comment: Put it in your controller tests, just inside the first `describe` block.

Comment: In spec - I have controllers the registration_controller is where I put it as follows to no avail:
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do

  describe "GET 'edit'" do
    before :each do
      request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'edit'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end

Comment: I'd suggest you make a new question. That's pretty hard to read!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my already open question on the matter here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102511/infamous-abstractcontrolleractionnotfound-devise-rails

Comment: See this wiki page: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29

Comment: You're brilliant. How on earth did you figure this out?

Comment: took me forever to find this answer. Thanks. For those using newer version and might encounter `Devise::MissingWarden` error refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421853/why-is-my-rspec-not-loading-devisetestcontrollerhelpers)

Answer (score -2):

Your route should look like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } do
  get "/users/sign_up/:invitation_token" => 'registrations#new'
end
```

Comment: That's what I have? The only difference is the hash synatax -> `registrations:` vs `:registrations =>`. That shouldn't make a difference unless I run my app in Ruby < 1.9.2.

Comment: Ah, ok. Didnt know that. Never seen that syntax before.  Thanks.

Comment: ;) It's much nicer when you get used to it! I think it'll edit my question anyway, just in case It confuses anyone.