# Checking If Devise User Logged In In Application Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I am trying to use the application.html.erb file to create a navbar on all of my pages. I want some of the links to only show if a user is logged in, and some to show if a user is not logged in, so I have the following in views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
...
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    # Show some links
<% end %>

<% if not user_signed_in? %>
    # Show some other links
<% end %>
...
```

This works when I go to the site, but the issue comes when I try to test with rake.

When I run my tests, I get the following error:

> AppointmentsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
>   ActionView::Template::Error: Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
>   Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
>   If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.

All of the similar errors I found online do not seem to apply to this situation. I understand that there is an issue with Devise not being loaded while testing, but cannot figure out how to fix it. I have tried many different things and nothing has worked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421853/why-is-my-rspec-not-loading-devisetestcontrollerhelpers

Comment: I am not using RSpec so that solution doesn't work

Comment: That's true, I do think the issue is basically the same though. I've added an answer below that should work for unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

if your using Devise? try to use current_user.present? not user_signed_in

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= some links %>
<%else%>
  <%= some links %>
<% end %>
```

and in your ApplicationController add this

```
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the Devise test helpers:

```
class AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
end
```

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-tests