# Helper Devise: could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on request environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I try to use Devise for my Rails app. I can sign up and login but when I go to my other page "build" I get the following error:

> Devise::MissingWarden in Home#show Devise could not find the
>   `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment. Make sure that
>   your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the
>   `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack. If
>   you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are
>   either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are
>   using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the
>   `request.env['warden']` object for you.

Here is my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private
  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    build_path
  end
end
```

Here rea my two partial views:

```
<!-- views/devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb -->
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<!-- views/devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb -->
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

After debugging, I figured out that the problem is coming from this line in my "show" controller: template = HomeController.render('layouts/_template')

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this happening when you run the app locally, or when you run your test suite?

Comment: According to this answer, you cannot use Warden/Devise in a controller test (`ActionController::TestCase`) because it is Rack middleware and the Rack middleware is not loaded for controller tests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420923/configuring-warden-for-use-in-rspec-controller-specs/17050993#17050993

Comment: And maybe you can post the fix?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Based on this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422513/1299362) you need to include the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module in your controller specs. Add the following to your rails_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Comment: After debugging, I figured out that the problem is coming from this line in my "show" controller: template = HomeController.render('layouts/_template')

Comment: I hate it when the accepted answer has nothing to do with the original question.  The original post said nothing about specs, rspec or testing in general.  This is not the correct answer.

Comment: This happens on development env. How would add something in `railes_helper` help?

Answer (score 31):

It can happen when you call Devise methods, like `current_user`, in code being managed by action cable. like a background job to render comment or something else.

You may resolve it by doing something like the following in your controller. It propagates `warden` to the the @env['warden'] variable so that Devise can use it:

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(comment_params[:product_id])
  @comment = @product.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.save!

  gon.comment_id = @comment.id
  gon.comment_user_id = @comment.user_id

  ActionCable.server.broadcast "chat", comment: render_comment
  
  render :create, layout: false
end


def render_comment
  CommentsController.renderer.instance_variable_set(
    :@env, {
      "HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000", 
      "HTTPS"=>"off", 
      "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", 
      "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",   
      "warden" => warden
    }
  )

  CommentsController.render(
    partial: 'comments/comment_detail',
    locals: {
      product: @product,
      comment: @comment
    }
  )
end
```

This will help you resolve the warden issue, if you have used Devise's `current_user` in that partial, it will give you the commentor user (as it should since that user initiated the rendering of partial).

Now to solve this, if you have a front end framework you might need to fetch the current user from cookies in order to restrict some actions like edit/delete. but if you are working in pure rails the solution I came across is that you have to make a hidden field in the dom having current users id, and you will fetch that id for comparison in a script. you might need to access rails variables in javascript, for that you can use ***GON*** gem.

I know this answer might contain much more than asked but I've searched alot and no where I found a satisfactory solution to this problem, feel free to discuss.

Comment: This solution worked great for me in a similar context (not in specs as in the accepted answer). I've found an easier way to inject `warden` though, you can just do `CommentsController.renderer.new(warden: warden).render(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

Add

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
```

in your rails_helper.rb file.

Comment: That's probably only for RSpec.

Comment: Yes. Its for rspec only

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when testing views where 'current_user' was present in some conditional.

I solved it with this:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :customer }

before(:each) do
  allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  ...
```

Comment: This is good - but you'll want to update `FactoryGirl` to `FactoryBot` as the gem has changed name since you left this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having this problem outside of Rspec say you were trying to render a view within an `ActionCable` channel, a scalable/maintainable approach is to use a helper or a view library like [ViewComponents](https://viewcomponent.org/)/[cells](https://github.com/trailblazer/cells). This way, you can extract your existing view into a component and parameterize any devise/warden methods called in the view. The advantage of this approach is

1. The view is easier to test
2. You can call it from anywhere in your code
3. There are no coupled dependencies

Example using view helpers

Say you have in `app/views/messages/show.html.erb` the following

```
<%= current_user.first_name %>
<%= @message %>
```

Calling `MessagesController.render :show` outside the controller will cause an error since access to the request object is not available. Using ViewComponents, we extract the view into its own component

in `app/components/message_component.rb`

```rb
class MessageComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(user:, message:)
    @user = user
    @message = message
  end
end
```

in `app/components/message_component.html.erb`

```
<%= @user.first_name %>
<%= @message %>
```

Usage

In `app/views/messages/show.html.erb` just call

```
<%= render(MessageComponent.new(message: @message, user: current_user) %>
```

In ActionCable, call it like so

```rb
ApplicationController.render(MessageComponent.new(message: @message, user: current_user)
```

Since you have access to `ActiveRecord` models from anywhere in your code, you should be able to fetch `@message`

Answer (score 2):

Well, i have faced the same issue "devise could not find the warden :: proxy in actioncable" It can be resolved by passing the current `user_id` to your perform method in your job as you might be accessing the current user in your view which you rendering through broadcast and due to this issue was caused

Answer (score 1):

I have to use the current_user in the helper method, which was used in view of which I was writing specs.

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
before do
 allow(helper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

but if you are working on view specs then do this

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
before do
 allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

Answer (score -3):

I had this error and could not find answer anywhere else. It was after dropping and creating the db. But I didn't load the schema.

This fixed it:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```