# Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, devise, docker-compose, warden

I found some SO answers about this problem. I have this error when I load the web from the Docker container.

I tried what's is suggested here

[Helper Devise: could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on request environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910712/helper-devise-could-not-find-the-wardenproxy-instance-on-request-environmen) but no success

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0
ENV PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64"

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y rake  less rsync locales build-essential chrpath libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libssl-dev libxft-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x nodejs yarn pdftk && \
    curl -L -O https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 && \
    mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share && \
    ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin && \
    mkdir -p /root/.phantomjs/2.1.1/x86_64-linux/bin && \
    ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /root/.phantomjs/2.1.1/x86_64-linux/bin/phantomjs && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN sed -i "s/^#\ \+\(en_US.UTF-8\)/\1/" /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV RAILS_ENV=development
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /box

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And I have a docker composer file when I create the image of the database (postgresql) and the image of the rails server.

When all the container are loaded, I go to to my browser and I get this in the terminal:

> Error during failsafe response: Devise could not find the
>   `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment. Make sure that
>   your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the
>   `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack. If
>   you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are
>   either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are
>   using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the
>   `request.env['warden']` object for you.

Note: I'm using Ruby 2.4.0 in local and in Docker