# Use current_user in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise for authentication. In my User model there is a field "locale", which I want to use in the application controller for the current logged in user. So I have this in the application controller:

```
    @user = User.current_user.locale
```

But this doesn't work. How can I access fields of the current user in the application controller? And devise hasn't created a users controller, where can I find that when I want to make some changes there? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user` is already User object, just call locale on it :

```
@user = current_user
locale = current_user.locale
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is an instance method, meaning you can only call it on (or within) an *instance* of the `User` class. When you do `User.current_user` you're trying to call it as a class method, i.e. a method on the User *class* itself.

If you *really* need to use `current_user` within `ApplicationController`--at best a code smell and at worst a really bad idea--you can fall back on [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki), which Devise is built on top of. E.g.:

```
user = env['warden'].current_user
user.locale
```

As for your other question regarding controllers, [it has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller).

Comment: That's not working: undefined method `current_user' for #<Warden This what I have: user = env['warden'].current_user
    I18n.locale = user.locale

Comment: Ah, having not worked with Warden directly before I may have been wrong, or anyway can't solve that. Could you back up and show us the code you would like to put in `ApplicationController`, and tell us why it's most appropriate there rather than in another controller?

Comment: #Jordan, I think your are wrong, Devise set current_user as an helper (returning an instance variable) for ApplicationController, allowing to access it directly in controller and views. It is not related with warden (even if it is build using warden env).

Answer (score 0):

current_user is available as usual in the application controller.
to access it in every request (in your application controller):

```
before_filter :get_locale

def get_locale
  @user = current_user
  locale = @user.locale
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is not available in `application_controller` as it extends `base`.
Simple solution is to use it like that

```
before_action :user_full_name

def user_full_name
 @user_full_name = current_user.fname + ' ' + current_user.lname
end
```