# Devise: User belongs_to organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication, and on the Sign Up page I have a text field for 'organization' so when the user signs up, they will create an organization, and I want the user to be associated with that organization (user model has organization_id attribute). I have created the devise views, and added a fields_for for the organization name. In my models I have User belongs_to :organization and Organization has_many :users (there will be more than one user associated to organizations). I have been down every path I could find trying to do this without modifying the controller, but have had no luck. Please don't suggest doing this without modifying the controller unless you have a sample app where you have implemented it that you can point to.

I have created a registrations controller as is laid out here: [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

I just threw a few puts statements in the controller, and I don't see those being displayed on the console, so it looks like I am not getting to this controller.

I also copied my views from app/view/devise/registrations to app/views/registrations after which my views *seem* to come from outer space! The organization field I created no longer is displayed, and I can't seem to tell where the view is loaded from.

Sorry for not being more succinct, but I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: the views are not coming from outer space but from the devise gem - you must have run the generator to create the views that you edited I think, but if they are not created the views in the gem are used instead.  As to your main question, you say you used fields_for - does user have accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Comment: Thanx! Now I know where the view was coming from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your User model ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html))

It should look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In views you could use Rails helper or create field by hand:

```
<input type="text" name="user[organization_attributes][name]">

<% user = User.new(organization => Organization.new) %>
<%= form_for user do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for user.organization do |organization_form| %>
    <%= organization_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:
Your devise view should look like:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<% resource.organization ||= Organization.new %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <%= f.fields_for resource.organization do |organization_form| %> 
    <div><%= organization_form.label :name %><br />
    <%= organization_form.text_field :name %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Hey Marek, here is what I am trying in my view https://gist.github.com/1335581 I am getting the error: NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new
Showing /home/jlocklear/railsApps/devise/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0xb650452c>:0xb65035dc>

Extracted source (around line #11):
...
11:  <%= form_for user do |form| %>

Comment: It was example how to do it. I also added how the Devise view should look like.

Comment: Hey Marek. I tried this, and still no cigar! Here is what I am seeing on the console. Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-03 08:53:20 -0400
  ..., "user"=>{"email"=>"adssmin@abtech.edu", "organization"=>{"name"=>"test"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: organization
Note the warning. I tried adding attr_accessible :organization but no change in behaviour.

Comment: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: organization >>> this means that you should add attr_accesible :organization_attributes to user model.

Comment: And probably you have to change <%= f.fields_for resource.organization do |organization_form| %> to <%= f.fields_for :organization do |organization_form| %>

Comment: You nailed it homeboy! I added edits to your answer and accepted. Thanx!