# overriding devise after_sign_up_path_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In routes i have the root-path pointing `"home#index"` but when i try to override  that with after_sign_up_path_for keeps redirecting me to the root path when I sign in or sign up. I have tried to put it in both in devise subclassed controller and application_controller, but it didn't work. What do I need to do here?

Application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    show_cities_path(resource)
  end
end
```

registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    show_cities_path(resource)
  end
end
```

routes

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked your show_cities_path exists, by executing `rake routes`? Might be worth having a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out

Answer (score 96):

If you also have the Confirmable module enabled, you have to override `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` since a new sign-up is "inactive" until it's confirmed. `after_sign_up_path_for` doesn't seem to get called when Confirmable is active.

Comment: Worth noting that this applies to all cases where a user is inactive for login, for instance if you override `active_for_authentication?` This includes the confirmable case where the user is inactive for login until they confirm their account.

Comment: In fact, at the current point in time, you have to note that the method will not be over-ridden by a similarly named method in `ApplicationController` - you have to declare your own controller for `:registrations`, in which you need to insert this sole method (`after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`).

Answer (score 20):

Although I am late to the game, I just ran into this problem and had trouble finding the solution.

If you are using your own RegistrationsController to customize Devise, then you need to add the after_sign_up_path_for(resource) method to that controller instead of ApplicationController.

In registrations_controller.rb:

```
private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_page_path
  end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: Even thought the OP question might have been served better by another answer, this one was the problem I was having!

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this problem until realizing I had forgotten to declare that I was overriding devise's registrations controller. In my case, I'm using devise with the :user resource, so I added this to routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

After that, the redirect that I specified in after_inactive_sign_up_path_for worked.

[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) has a more complete discussion on this topic, with alternative ways of declaring overrides.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can view the source code of devise to solve the problem and it's easy.

`devise-3.4.1 $ vim app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb`

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

As code show:

```
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        ...
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

      else
        ...
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
```

Comment: This answer allowed me to realize that if you are using the `confirmable` module you need to overwrite the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method instead of the `after_sign_up_path_for` method. This is because the user won't sign in right away, it needs to confirm the email first, so Devise won't call `after_sign_up_path_for`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just blown about 2 hours on this, but LiveReload was my issue. I was being redirected successfully but LiveReload was picking up the change on development.sqllite and overriding the request.

Answer (score 0):

#### If using OmniAuth custom callback controllers with Rails 5.2:

In my particular case, the after sign up path was not working: but I was using OmniAuth with a custom callback controller, which was invoking the `after_sign_in_path_for` rather than the former:

def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

```
if @user.persisted?
  # Here's the guilty line your honour:
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Google") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.google_oauth2_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

end

........And the `sign_in_and_redirect` path redirects to the `after_sign_in_path_for` method. So I generated a new devise controller for sessions and simply overrode that method. problem solved!