# rails devise: adding extras on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using the devise gem for rails for app.

My question is after user creates the account I want him/her to create a profile as well. I want both to happen at the same time so I can do a 1-1 match with the user id and profile id.

How can I do this?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it so the `user` model has a `has_one` relationship with a `profile` model, and give the user model an `after_create` callback which creates a profile.  What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: what if the user signs in but dont create a profile? That will destroy my model because I want to do a 1-1 with the ids.

Comment: how do you give the user model a after_create call back? I think devise hides the model and controller implementations?

Comment: Use a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to make the profile creation happen behind the scenes.  Did you want a custom sign up screen so they have to enter in attributes for the profile?  I think Devise allows you to do that if you want.

Comment: [Here is a link to a question where someone has described how to override the registration and sign_in screen for Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller).

Comment: Yes I want to do that. However, how do I generate the controllers for devise classes?

Comment: Well [looking at what one of the users who answered has done in the last link I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4527049/995874), you may not even need to generate a new controller.  It looks like you can create your own custom registration form at `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`, and then it will use that for the registration form when creating, and you can specify your custom fields on the user model, and put the fields for it on this form.