# Devise redirect after sign up fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there any easy way to disable devise sign_up page? I have forms for registration and authorization on one page so i don't need any other pages. I want to disable routes responsible for these pages, so that if a user enters `users/sign_up` he should't get to the sign up page but should be redirected to some other page.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Did you change the `respond_with`?

Comment: @Ashitaka
Finally i skipped all devise default routes and specified a list of `post` and `get` routes mapped to devise controllers. Then i overrided   
devise controllers to use `respond_with({}, :location => after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource))` when authentication or registration or password restore fails. Note that you have to create a method `after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource)`. Inside it just put where you want to go(for_example `home_path`). That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the registrations controller and make the `new` action redirect somewhere.  [Here are some responses to a similar question that was posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) which explain the necessary steps.

Comment: #Batkins, 
`clean_up_passwords resource;
 respond_with resource`
This code is executed when there are errors during registration(ex. a user exists, empty email). If i write `redirect_to some_path` after this code i get double render exception. If i write `redirect_to some_path` instead of `respond_with resource` i am redirected but `devise_error_messages` are empty so i can't use them in the view i'm redirected to. Is there any way to make error messages available in the view i'm redirected to?

Comment: You need to use `redirect_to some_path and return`.  That will make it stop executing code within that method after the redirect code occurs which will prevent other render/redirect statements that might occur afterwards.  [Read this documentation on the RoR official site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors) for a more detailed explanation.