# different sign-in view depending on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise2 and Rails3.  I'd like to show a differently formatted sign-in view depending on the route (users/foo vs users/bar).  I'm not sure where to hook in this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to create your own devise controller with 2 actions foo and bar. Look here for some inspiration [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)