# application.rb paths.app.views undefined method `app' for Rails::Paths::Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

using devise 2.1.0

I had to override the devise registration controller.  In the process I had to move my devise views directory to correspond with the new controller.  I have this code in my config/applications.rb file

```
    paths.app.views << "app/views/devise"
```

And it is throwing an error when I try and start my server with `rails s`:

```
    ...config/application.rb:65:in `<class:Application>': undefined method `app' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000103537740> (NoMethodError)
```

I am relatively new at rails. But I get that there is a root class somewhere that didn't define app.  I got this advice to use this `paths.app.views` here at stack.

Here is the full applications.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Growle
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]

    #don't generate RSpec tests for views and helper
    config.generators do |g|
      g.view_specs false
      g.helper_specs false
    end

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    paths.app.views << "app/views/devise"
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Folders inside app/views/ will be automatically loaded.

Comment: Show your full application.rb

Comment: @KevinSjöberg what I am really trying to do is to have a `user` that `belongs_to` a `pricing_plan`. So I wanted to override the register controller of devise so that I could send the `pricing_plan` as an instance variable to the register new.html.erb view. In order to do that once I overrode the register controller I had read that I needed to show rails that my views for register controller were in app/views/devise.  I hope that makes sense. If you guys know of a better way to do this whole thing I am ready to hear it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the last comment of yours, it sound that you want either [view_paths=](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods/view_paths%3D) or [prepend_view_path](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods/prepend_view_path).

Those can be set at class level in your controller.

If that isn't what you are looking for, consider reading [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) for information.

Comment: `view_paths=` seems to work wonderfully. I think it may be an even better answer then the paths.app.views because it is on a single controller basis.