# Rails Devise Override Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working with Devise and I am trying to override the registrations controller.

I have followed posts on here with no luck.

This is what I have:

```
 class AccountsController::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end
 end

   devise_for :accounts, :controllers => {:registrations => "accounts/registrations"} do
     get "welcome" => "accounts#new", :as => :new_account
   end
```

I also created an account folder in views and added the new view.

I receive the following error:

```
 app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

@Brian is correct it will work but you want your code have to work just change:

```
class AccountsController::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

to:

```
class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Then create an accounts folder in the controller folder and place this file to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a little different, but this solved the problem. [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

```
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def new
    @test = "test"
    super
end
  end
```

The I added the following to my views registrations/new.html.erb

Then:

```
  devise_for :accounts, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} do
  get "welcome" => "registrations#new", :as => :new_account
  end
```