# Rails Devise prevent login immediately after Signup without using Confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

Use Case:

1. Admin should be able to create user, and it should not attempt to login.
2. Public User can crate account and after signup he should be redirected to sign-in page rather signing him in immediately.

Can somebody help me with this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is to override Devise's RegistrationsController create method.

There is an excellent explanation for how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller).

This is Devise create action:

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

After you override the controller, just remove `sign_in(resource_name, resource)`

You can also set the method `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` to fit your needs

Comment: Note : with the newer version, the `sign_in(resource_name, resource)` is replace with `sign_up(resource_name, resource)`. It does exactly the same thing, but allows you to override only the sign_up method in your controller.

Comment: replace `expire_session_data_after_sign_in!` with `expire_data_after_sign_in!`