# Devise Custom login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

Is there any way to point the Devise authenticator at my custom login form? The standard, unstyled form is unusable (Fields missing, throws exceptions on submit, actually crashed my runtime once.) and just not good looking. I have a 100% usable form, one that actually logs people in, but if a mistake is made, the standard form shows up, also lacking an error message. Something like "When asked to present a login form, render /views/sys/login.html.erb, and on error, return to that view and put in error message"
NOTE: I have already tried the below, from a different question

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => "system/login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

and this simply overwrites my form

(My `/system/` from HTTP gets files out of the `/sys/` views directory, so `http://localhost:3000/system/login` would render `/views/sys/login.html.erb`)

EDIT: Never developed a rails app that uses login or authentication with web forms (Only the standard HTTP authentication)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can move devise views to your views directory using the following command (from your rails project root):

```
rails g devise:views
```

this it will create `devise` directory in your `app/views/`. There you will get all of it's views and you can customise it as you prefer. For customising the login form, you need to modify the `sessions/new.html.*` file. * may be `.erb` or `.haml` or something else

Comment: @Josh In the future read through the readme for the plugins you use.  Devise has almost all questions answered (including yours) here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I thought I read through the readme and did not find this documented. My apologies.

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar for devise models and controllers? What's the simplest way to modify those?

Comment: for controller, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller