# Devise: how to disallow logging different roles from the same session, at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

I created three different roles (User, Admin, Manager) using devise's rails generator, they are stored in different tables and models...

How can I forbid someone to to login two different roles during the same session?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? Devise will create different session variables based on the name of the model.

Comment: I don't want the same person to log in as User and as Admin in the same browser window.

Answer (score 0):

When a user tries to log in you can verify he isn't logged in as another role.
To do that you will have to override devise SessionsController. It is explained [here for RegistrationsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) but the same can be done with SessionsController.
Next add a before filter to your new SessionsController:

```
before_filter :require_not_authenticated_in_other_scopes, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Then just implement the filter in the controller:

```
def require_not_authenticated_in_other_scopes
  other_types = [:user, :admin, :manager] - [resource_name]
  other_types.each do |type|
    if self.send("#{type}_signed_in?") 
      resource = warden.user(type)
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

I've taken parts of the implementations from Devise's SessionsController itself you can find it in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb).