# Rails 3.2: nested_attributes and has_one association, in two differents forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes, form-for

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for on a has_one association model.

I have two models, a user and a profile. A user has one profile:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email,:profile_attributes
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

I have two forms on the edit user page. One that updates the main user attributes (and works fine and not shown below) and then this one that allows the user to upload an avatar:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {id: 'avatar_form' ,:multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.file_field :avatar %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This submit doesn't work, i get this error message:

**NoMethodError in UsersController#update**

**undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

My UsersController code for update is:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

And the Params are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"YTpGnj9uIpybDAgf4c6pxMydY15ga5GZ++FBMe/6dV4=",
"user"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2303e08 @original_filename="test.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_attributes][avatar]\";  filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
"id"=>"3"}},
"commit"=>"Upload",
"id"=>"1"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: is your user signed in? I mean if `current_user` is nil, you will get this error message - so this can't work when no used is logged in

Comment: Yes, the user is signed in, i have the **before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:home, :update, :edit]**.

Comment: Solved it! I had some authorization problems whit the tmp folder, changed it with 
`def cache_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end`

Answer (score 0):

Add to your user controller

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.profile.build
  #or
  #@user.build_profile

end
```

To better understand what is happening try to add gem "better_errors" to your Gemfile

```
gem "better_errors"
```

you will get a kind of console, where you might type

```
@user
```

and as output you will get (nil, or obj). If nil, you definitely forge this line in new action

```
@user = User.new
```

If you are using divise for auto. backed, rewrite controller like here
[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey 
As regarding has_one relation, 
@user.profile.build does not work, need to choose the below, @user.build_profile
Some told me as below:
"if the association was defined using has_one, we use the "build_association" function. For has_many, it should be "association.build".