# How to avoid signup in devise to return token on creation of new user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have devise for authentication and when i create users as

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept:
>   application/json'   -X POST htt://localhost:3000/users.json  -d
>   "{'user' : { 'username' : 'sample@example.com', 'password' : 'password', 'password_confirmation' : 'password' 
>   }}"

the response for the above request is

> {"user":{"authentication_token":"uwAqF4SG8kPirxWN35yp",
>   "username":"sample@example.com"}}

but i want the response to be

```
{"New user created successfully"}
```

how can i change so as to get the required response? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

registration controller create method is as follows but how could i do it as you have said

```
build_resource

            if resource.save
                if resource.active_for_authentication?
                    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
                    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
                    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
                    else
                    set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
                    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
                    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
                end
                else
                clean_up_passwords(resource)
                respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
            end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your update and the answer by tw airball, the code would be

```
respond_to do |format|
  if resource.save
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      format.html { respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource) }
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
      expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
      format.html { respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource) }
    end
    format.json { render json: flash } # respond with the standard devise flash message
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    format.html { respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new } }
    format.json { render json: "User not created" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the default behaviour is a correct response -- it is returning the JSON object of new (successfully) created user for a JSON request.

Anyway, take a look at this post: [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

You will want to override the registrations controller for the create action something like:

```
def create 
    #custom logic here
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #some logic here
      format.json {"New user created successfully"}
    end
end
```