# How to override gem controller action Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have **Devise** gem for user authentication.
Basically, I want to override registrations_controller.rb in Devise gem locally. The code in gem:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
   ...
    def update
        ...(need to override)
    end
end
```

I want to redirect user to other page if particular attribute in **edit_form** is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against overriding that method. Instead, take a look at the [Wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile) about custom redirects after a profile edit. It explains to override this method:

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  user_path(resource)
end
```

You could return different paths based on your attribute, so for example

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  resource.foo? ? foo_path : bar_path
end
```

Comment: thanks it works. I found also this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller, just added devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" } in routes.rb and I can override it