# How can I add transaction before updating when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using act_as_taggable_on with Devise.
Each user can set up their tags up to 3tags maximum on their profile edit page.
Before it does save, I'd like to have transaction something like this below.
This is the one I implemented for my community model that is made by scaffold.

```
params[:community][:tag_list] = params[:community][:tag_list].gsub(/[ ]+/," ")
params[:community][:tag_list] = params[:community][:tag_list].gsub(/[.]+/,",")
```

I have no idea when doing this using Devise on side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code to Model to handle this functionality.

```
alias_method :super_tag_list=, :tag_list=
def tag_list=(tag_names)
  self.super_tag_list = tag_names.gsub(/[ ]+/," ").gsub(/[.]+/,",")
end
```

Comment: Thanks! but it says super: no superclass method `tag_list=' for #<User:0x0000001770de08>

Comment: Add the `acts_as_taggable` before the method.

Comment: I have it 'acts_as_taggable_on  :tags'

Comment: Aha!! thanks now it works!! You're super engineer!! :) If you could, please answer my another question:)

Comment: I mean this question about devise [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813776/how-can-i-set-the-value-to-the-nested-column-when-signing-up-with-devise)