# Performing "login or signup" in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to signup a new user if the email he has entered does not exist in the database. I have a custom sessions controller with the following code:

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)

scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
resource ||= resource_or_scope
sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
```

How do I instruct Devise to sign-up the user in the 'failure' method?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the [email only sign up method with Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How%20To%3a%20Email-only%20sign-up). Extending this you could have the failure method post to the registrations controller that you have setup to handle email only sign up.

**Update:**
One of the simplest ways would be to override respond as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated). Except in your case you may want something like this:

```
 def respond
   if http_auth?
     http_auth
   else
     user = User.create(..user information) #Create the user (register them)
     sign_in(user) # Sign in the user just created
     redirect  # Redirect to whatever page you want
   end
 end
```

This way you can have one email field and when the user does not get authenticated (the user does not exist, wrong password, etc) the user will be created. Of course for your case you may want to nest another `if` block in there to check if the user exists or not so you do not try to create another user just because the password is wrong etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide a snippet to demonstrate how to post to the registrations controller?

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting users that try to 'sign in' using the 'sign up' form. It has a lot to do with design choices, but I really like the idea of a catch all.

I just sort of found my own solution to this. I don't love it, but it was pretty simple (once I finally figured it out). I overrode the `RegistrationsController` as detailed [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller). It's the registrations form that I have on the main page of my site for several reasons, so it seemed fitting to do it there.

You'll need to create the `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb` and put the code in there:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # This is where the magic happens. We actually check the validity of the
    # username (an email in my case) and password manally.
    email = params[:user][:email]
    if user = User.find_by_email(email)
      if user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
        sign_in(user)
        redirect_to '/'
        return
      end
    end


    # Default devise stuff
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

You'll **need to be sure to configure your routes to use this controller** as detailed in that other SO post I linked to above.

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Good luck!