# Jcrop Rails, Devise and the Railscasts #182 revised

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jcrop

So i have a little "i'm stuck' moment again.

Victim is a rails app with devise and want to implement Jcrop in it.

I orientated myself on the Railscasts #182 revised, because it fits nearly everything that my enviroment has/needs (Carrierwave upload) - so current status: Upload works and images are resized properly. My Problem is now - the Jcrop-Box doesn't appear.

As far as i saw in the code, this part (to be found [here](https://github.com/railscasts/182-cropping-images-revised/blob/master/cropper-after/app/controllers/users_controller.rb)):

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      if params[:user][:avatar].present?
        render :crop
      else
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Successfully updated user."
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

handles the triggering of the crop file which has the cropbox (which can be found [here](https://github.com/railscasts/182-cropping-images-revised/tree/master/cropper-after/app/views/users))

But as far as i belive to know, the user controller actions for update and new are handled by devise. Has anyone an idea what i could do or how i can trigger the events on another way?

Comment: Did you try override RegistrationsController yet? 
for how to do that [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Comment: And here for [original code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) for RegistrationsController.

Comment: As you see if you didn't touch password this will not take effect with devise. That mean you can create another controller to crop image.