# How can I pass email of unconfirmed user to the session (Devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, session, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a registration form, and after registration I want browser to remember user's (still unconfirmed) email. How could I do that? I assume I can do this somehow with `build_resource` of `RegistrationsController`.

Comment: What have you done yet and could be more specific on "I want browser to remember"?

Comment: You can access user obj you're creating with `@user = build_resource` in your devise overwritten controller if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remember the last registered/un-confirmed user you could do this:

Create new folder under app/controllers called **my_devise**

Create a file called **registrations_controller.rb** in **app/controllser/my_devise**:

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      # here we save the registering user in a session variable
      session[:registered_as] = resource 
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

end
```

Update the **config/routes.rb** file to tell Devise to use our new controller:

```
devise_for :users, 
    :controllers  => {
      :registrations => 'my_devise/registrations'
    }
```

After registration, the session variable **:registered_as** will now hold the last user that registered and could be referenced in any controller or view:

some_view.html.rb:

```
<p>Registered as: 

<%= session[:registered_as].inspect %>

</p>
```

See also: [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)