# Can't mass-assign protected attributes for creating a has_many nested model with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I've watched the RailsCast, another nested attributes video, lots of SO posts, and fought with this for a while, but I still can't figure it out. I hope it's something tiny.

I have two models, `User` (created by Devise), and `Locker` (aka, a product wishlist), and I'm trying to create a `Locker` for a `User` when they sign up. My login form has a field for the name of their new `Locker` (aptly called `:name`) that I'm trying to assign to the locker that gets created upon new user registration. All I'm ever greeted with is:

`WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: locker`

I've tried every combination of `accepts_nested_attributes` and `attr_accesible` in both of my models, yet still nothing works. I can see from the logs that it's being processed by the Devise#create method, and I know Devise isn't smart enough to create my models how I want :)

Here's the relevant bits of my two models:

```
# user.rb    
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :locker_attributes

  # Associations
  has_many :lockers
  has_many :lockups, :through => :lockers

  # Model nesting access
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lockers
end
```

and

```
# locker.rb
class Locker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lockups
  has_many :products, :through => :lockups 

  attr_accessible :name, :description
end

# lockers_controller.rb (create)
    @locker = current_user.lockers.build(params[:locker])
    @locker.save
```

I'm assuming I need to override Devise's `create` method to somehow get this to work, but I'm quite new to rails and am getting used to the black box "magic" nature of it all.

If anyone can help me out, I'd be incredibly thankful. Already spent too much time on this as it is :)

**EDIT:** I realized I omitted something in my problem. My `Locker` model has three attributes - `name`, `description` (not mandatory), and `user_id` to link it back to the `User`. My signup form only requires the `name`, so I'm not looping through all the attributes in my nested form. Could that have something to do with my issue too?

**EDIT 2:** I also figured out how to override Devise's `RegistrationsController#create` method, I just don't know what to put there. Devise's whole `resource` thing doesn't make sense to me, and browsing their source code for the `RegistrationsController` didn't help me much either.

*And for bonus points:* When a user submits the login form with invalid data, the `Locker` field always comes back blank, while the regular Devise fields, username & email, are filled in. Could this also be fixed easily? If so, how?

Comment: how are you creating the Locker? Can you post the controller code?

Comment: I posted my Lockers#create method, but I don't think my code is even getting to that. I think Devise is trying to create the User and just bypassing my controller code. I could be wrong though.

Comment: that should be easy to check, just add a `debugger` line in the controller and see if it stops there.

Comment: @mihai If all I had to do was install the debugger gem and add `debugger` to the line in my controller above where my new Lockers are built, it didn't fire. As I suspected, it looks like I'll have to override Devise' User#create method.

Comment: yes, about the debugger that's all you had to do

Comment: Forgot to update you. The `debugger` breakpoint never triggered, again confirming that I need to somehow hack into Devise's `RegistrationsController#create` method, but I don't know how. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone helped me figure out the solution in a more "Rails 4'y" way with `strong attributes` & how to override Devise's `sign_up_params` (to catch all the data coming from my signup form).

```
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :lockers_attributes)
 end
```

Gemfile addition: `gem 'strong_parameters'`

Commenting out the `attr_accessible` statement in my `user.rb` file, since apparently strong parameters eliminate the need for `attr_accessible` declarations.

```
 # attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :lockers
```

And the/a correct way of building a Locker before submitting the form: at the beginning of the nested form:

`<%= l.input :name, :required => true, label: "Locker name", :placeholder => "Name your first locker" %>`

Thanks again for all your help. I know a question like this is difficult to answer without seeing the whole codebase.

Answer (score 2):

first, you have a typo :

```
attr_accessible :locker_attributes
```

should be plural :

```
attr_accessible :lockers_attributes
```

then, the standard way to use `nested_attributes` is :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%# fields_for will iterate over all user.lockers and 
      build fields for each one of them using the block below,
      with html name attributes like user[lockers_attributes][0][name].
      it will also generate a hidden field user[lockers_attributes][0][id]
      if the locker is already persisted, which allows nested_attributes
      to know if the locker already exists of if it must create a new one
  %>
  <% f.fields_for :lockers do |locker_fields| %>
    <%= locker_fields.label      :name %>
    <%= locker_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and in you controller :

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.lockers.build
end

def create
  # no need to use build here : params[:user] contains a
  # :lockers_attributes key, which has an array of lockers attributes as value ;
  # it gets assigned to the user using user.lockers_attributes=, 
  # a method created by nested_attributes
  @user = User.new( params[:user] )
end
```

as a side note, you can avoid building a new locker for new users in controller in different ways:

- create a factory method on `User`, or override `new`, or use an `after_initialize` callback to ensure every new user instantiated gets a locker builded automatically
- pass a specific object to `fields_for` :

  ```
  <% f.fields_for :lockers, f.object.lockers.new do |new_locker_fields| %>
  ```

Comment: I completely appreciate your answer, and I think you're on the right track (because I understand where you're going with it), but the mass-assignment error is happening in Devise#create, and I have no idea where that is.  I can already create `Users`, `Lockers`, etc, it's just the new feature of automagically creating a locker for the user upon registration isn't working. Seems like I need to dig into Devise, but I don't know how.

Comment: oh, did not understand that the problem was from Devise. Did you know you can override Devise controllers ? see [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started), section "configuring controllers"

Comment: oh, and the method you need to override is `new_with_session` on `User`. There's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised?view=asciicast) about it, but unfortunately it's not free... another option is to override `build_resource` on your controller.

Comment: Hmm, I checked both the `new_with_session` instances in Devise: one deals with facebook login, and the other only has this line `new(params)`. Not sure how I'd work with either of those. Also tried my hand at modifying all three places `build_resource` is mentioned, but I just screwed things up. Seems like Devise just tosses out any parameters related to `Locker` once the user hits the submit button.