# When overriding the registration controller from devise, is it possible to access the newly created user on the create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder right after a user registers, so I override the create action on the registration controller (devise) but I don't know how to access the newly created user in order to create the folder with it's name to upload files later.

So far I've got this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    create_folder
  end
  
  def update
    super
  end
  
  def create_folder
    path =  Pathname.new(':rails_root/tmp/')
    directory_name = ":current_user"
    Dir.mkdir(path, directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) to override the registration controller.

1. Should I leave it there or move it to the create action? Instead of using a method
2. is that the right way to access the current user?
3. Maybe instead of registration it's better to do it on sign in?

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You should be using an `after_filter` for this type of functionality. I've added an answer below demonstrating how this can be done, replete with commentary regarding fixing code/syntactical errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really be accomplishing this functionality in an `after_filter` to your action, rather than in the action itself:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_filter :create_folder, :only => :create

  protected

  def create_folder
    path =  Pathname.new(Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/') #=> Note 1
    directory_name = resource.id.to_s                #=> Note 2
    Dir.mkdir(path + directory_name)                #=> Note 3
  end
end
```

**Notes**:

1. Your syntax for retrieving the project root is incorrect. `:rails_root` can't be interpolated from within single quotes - and it doesn't exist, anyways. Try `Rails.root.to_s` instead.
2. `":current_user"` is simply a string that will attempt to name the directory `:current_user`, which is neither dynamic nor valid. Because your Devise controller has access the the current `resource` (which in this case, represents the `current_user`), retrieve the `resource.id` and use it instead.
3. Concatenate the `path` and `directory_name` together with `+`, not `,`. There's no need for the `unless` conditional, since you're presumably only creating the new folder upon creation of a new user, and each user has a unique `id`.

Comment: The only thing i changed was path + directory_name to path.to_s + directory_name.to_s because it threw can't convert Fixnum into String error. Thank you very, very much. Now I just need how to access the current_user in a model to know what folder to look for. Thank you very very much again.

Comment: Very right regarding the error – I've updated the code to reflect.