# Customizing devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to customize devise session & registration controller.
I am even adding Active Admin to the app.

What is the correct process to override these controllers?

& I want to use both the controllers(customized as well as original). Is it possible?

- Active Admin - original devise controllers
- normal user - customized controllers.

When we are creating customized controllers, does same name cause any problem?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: This queston has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a admin role to your devise, have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role. 
If you want to customise your current devise You can customise the devise views by copying the views from the gem into your application and then modifying them. The below line would copy the views into your application

```
rails generate devise:views
```

If you want to modify controllers, Follow below steps

1. You would have to create your own customise controller say Admins::SessionsController

   ```
   class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   end
   ```

Note that in the above example, the controller needs to be created in the app/controller/admins/ directory.

1. Now tell the router to use this controller

   ```
    devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
   ```
2. And since we changed the controller, it won't use the "devise/sessions" views, so remember to copy "devise/sessions" to "admins/sessions".

There is a rail cast video for active admin at http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I am doing is - Already I have all the setup & running project. I have Active Admin integrated. I need to now customize devise controllers. Currently its user/sign_in. As I will be moving devise controllers to app/controllers, should I need to create a new folder as app/controller/user/sessions_controllers.rb ?

Comment: If you are creating your customised controller and if you want to have namespace in it then the controller should be placed in the namespace folder. You could use the following code rails generate controller admin/Users