# Rails How can I restrict the total number of Devise users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reasons, I want to restrict the total number of Devise users, the new user won't save when greater than this number.

But I don't know how to do that, I didn't see any content about it in Devise doc.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: But can you explain the difference between that two answers?

Comment: Sure. This is a model validation issue for your Devise users, so placing this logic is the controller does not follow Model-View-Controller.

Comment: And your using Rails which is designed around MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing this within your model is more appropriate then your controller. 
Below is an example of this:

```
class Moderator < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_moderator_limit

  private
  devise  :database_authenticatable,
          :trackable,
          :validatable,
          :timeoutable,
          :registerable

  def check_moderator_limit
    if Moderator.count > 3
      return false
    end
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes but can you customize the error displayed to the user when you do that in the model ?

Comment: Sure, think of it as a custom validation.

Comment: I did not think of that, so yeah you should do it in the model then.

Comment: Why would you call ".all.lenght" just to get the number ? That is not efficent.

Just use Moderator.size or Moderator.count

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the devise registration controller to count the number of users in your db before saving the user or you could add a before create callback in your user model to do the same.

However doing it in the user model will get your user an error that you cannot modify.

If you do it in your custom devise registration controller you could customize the error and how the application handle it.

[Customize Devise Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Comment: But how can I see this controller ?

Comment: You cannot see it. You have to create a new one that will inherit from the devise one and use your custom method. I added a new link to my post that will show you how to customize it

Comment: Avoid applying constraints on your models within controllers.