# Devise Registration Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise forms used in my Ruby on rails site...how can i set different route paths for both devise form..i tried to override the after_sign_up_path..but both the forms gets redirected to same path...

I want to set different paths for each form.

**Registrations Controller**

```
class Registrations Controller < Devise::Registrations Controller
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'root_path'
  end
end
```

Comment: Means after user successfully signed up, you want to redirect them different route ?

Comment: yes after signed up need to redirect to different routes

Comment: ok what is difference between both type of user?? i mean you can redirect after signed up on the basis of user type or something that you have

Comment: yes based on the user type i need to redirect the welcome pages after signed up

Comment: please post `routes.rb` and you forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this method calls when signup is success, so set your after signed up path here

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      if resource.invitation_type == "first" (please replace with actual invitation type here)
        user1_path(replace with actual path) 
      elsif resource.invitation_type == "second" (please replace with actual invitation type here)
       user2_path(replace with actual path)
      else
        root_path
      end
    end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is resource.type?

Comment: how you are storing the user type in DB? what is the name of your field that contains user type ?

Comment: invitation_type ..usere types are based on invitation_type stored in db

Comment: updated my answer...please check on the basis of invitation type there ans redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the application controller, put the code for after_sign_up_path_for path

```
#put these code inside applications_controller
def after_sign_up_path_for
   if #{your_specific_condition}

   else
    root_path
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware that if you want to override your registrations controller, you'll have to [include the new controller in your routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller):

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```