# Where is my registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

OS: Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.1
Devise

After I created the application, I installed Devise:

```
rails g devise:install
rails g devise:views
```

The devise views were generated. What I don't have is a registrations controller in the controllers folder. Wasn't devise supposed to create a registrations controller?

Comment: Why are you need devise controller? What do you want to do?

Comment: I am using it to build a sample application to manage a subscription list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use Devise's default controllers or add your own. Here is the link to the registrations controller:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Keep in mind, Devise handles actions a little differently if you're planning on adding records to the User model.

You'll need to add something like this to the registration controller if you plan on adding something like a username:

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

def update_sanitized_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:username,
                                                         :email,
                                                         :password,
                                                         :password_conf)}
end
```

You'll also need to add this to you routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
```

Comment: Do I add the registrations controller like this: rails g controller registration new edit?

Comment: @JosephMouhanna I simply added it manually and pasted in the info from devise. Create a new file app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

`Devise` not generate controller by default for app, app use built-in `devise` controllers. If you need `monkeypatch` `devise` controller you [need create them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller).