# Determine redirect paths after sign up with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I can have two types of users sign up on my app, "girls" and "boys". If a girl signs up I want to redirect to "/girls" and if a boy signs up I want to redirect to "/boys".

Is it possible to do custom redirection with Devise?

The closest docs I found are here: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in). The problem is I can't do any check to switch the redirect route.

Options I've considered:

1. Pass an additional URL param when user clicks "sign-up". like
   `?is_girl=1`.
2. After they click `sign-up`, when determining the redirect route, I could look at the users model and see if they're a girl or boy. Then redirect accordingly.

Comment: try to override create method for Devise::RegistrationsController - for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller (change redirect urls in action create directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume as part of the sign up process you ask them if they are a boy or girl and this is saved in the database.

So you would just need to do like the example in the Devise docs is showing

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.sex == 'boy'
      '/boy' # or you could create a route in routes.rb and do boy_path
    else
      '/girl' # with routes setup: girl_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks CaptChrisD! I've been looking through the docs, do you know if there is a method where I can take an action in a controller 1 time after signup? I didn't see any method in the docs like `after_sign_in`.