# Devise Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to work out how devise controls sign outs in a rails 3 app. I look at the routes for destroy session and it's

```
destroy_hr_partner_session GET    /hr_partners/sign_out(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

However, I cannot find a devise controller, or a session controller for that matter.

Clearly I;m missing something, can someone explain how this works?

Specifically, I need to customise the redirect after a session is destroyed

G

Answer (score 0):

It's not super obvious, but the controller is inside the devise gem. When you call `devise_for` in your `routes.rb` it sets those paths up for you.

For reference, here are the built-in controllers: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the devise github page, to [configure controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) you can create a controller that extends the devise ones and then override the functionality. 
Then tell your devise route to use your new controller (`devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "my_sessions" }`)

To see what the base functionality is, [explore the source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Devise already has a controlller compiled in the gem, but if you want to override it, then you can just create a controller. For more information, please have a look at this:

[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)