# Rails Simple_Form Multiple Select Checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, devise, simple-form-for

I'm new to Rails, and I'm having some issues with Simple_Form, Devise and checkboxes.

I have added some additional columns to my Devise model, including a column where I would like users to tick one-or-more checkboxes. Similar to this:

> Areas of Operation: [ ] England [ ] Wales [ ] Scotland

Everything is fine, but when I select multiple areas, then save, the selections do not save to the database.

---

Here's my **View code** [app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb]:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :areas, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => ["England", "Wales", "Scotland", "Northern Ireland"] %>

<% end %>
```

---

And here's my **ApplicationController code** [app/controllers/application_controller.rb]:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :areas
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :areas
 end
end
```

I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but I've been Googling for hours with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT:

Apologies. Here is the scheme for the Devise (actually named 'providers') table:

```
create_table "providers", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "organisation"
  t.string   "street"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "county"
  t.string   "postcode"
  t.string   "areas"
  t.string   "methods"
end

add_index "providers", ["email"], name: "index_providers_on_email", unique: true
add_index "providers", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_providers_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Comment: You provided too little information. What is your db schema (meaning how are areas represented in database)?.

Comment: Is `areas` an association?

Comment: @Lucas -- apologies. I have updated my question to include the schema.

Comment: @kobaltz No, `areas` is not an association. I was hoping to just include the checkbox options within the view code (as above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to save areas,

1) Best way is to create new model called area and have many-to-many associations with user.
   [check](https://github.com/rohineematale/project-management-system). This is basic app where user has many projects ascociations.

2) If you dont want to create separate area model then you can store area in one of column user's. Either you can [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) the column. Here you can store data in arr or hash form

3) Add before filter in user and before saving the user, join the areas and save it as string.

Comment: Hi @bunty. Thank you for the reply. I think (1) might be the way I have to go. With regard to (2) and (3), would I have to create my own Controller for Devise, [similar to this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)?

Comment: Not needed. Devise will save your areas in serialize format while creating you data. For (3) you need to create before save method in user model where you can pass array of areas, join it with commas and set it to areas field.

Comment: Forgive me -- I'm very new to Rails. Would you mind giving me some demo code for the model? I am very grateful for your support.

Comment: Hi.. you can refer https://github.com/rohineematale/demo . Here in user.rb file we are setting areas. When you want to access areas of user, you can get it using cities method of user. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! It has been invaluable to me.