# before_action Not Running Before Edit Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to perform some calculations based on integer values in the database for the "User" class. (using devise.) This is working correctly on **users/show.html.erb**, but not on **registration/edit.html.erb (localhost:3000/users/edit)**

To that end, I've set up the following in **users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_calc_vars, only: [:edit, :show]  

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # edit.html.erb
        format.xml { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.xml { render :xml => @user }
    end
end

protected


#Sets value for calculated variables
def set_calc_vars

    user_client = User.find(params[:id])

    @rev_left = user_client.revlimit - user_client.revused

end
```

On both pages, the code to display the value of @rev_left is:

```
<%= @rev_left %>
```

I'm not certain why set_calc_vars is running on show.html.erb but not edit.html.erb.

On show.html.erb it displays the correct integer value for the logged in user.
On edit.html.erb is displays nothing, suggesting the value is nil.

My routes are as follows:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:show]

root 'pages#home'
```

Comment: The `before_action` should be performed, seems fine.

Comment: Yeah that's what I don't get, when I go to users/id (where id= the id of the signed in user) it displays the correct value. When I go to users/edit, however, it displays nothing.

Comment: How does your routes look? Another comment is that you are getting your user from the database twice for each request. This could be performed in a before_filter aswell.

Comment: Just edited the original post to add my routes at the end. 

Do you mean I could just declare user_client as @user_client and delete the other two lines that pull users?

I was under the impression that before_action has replaced before_filter in the newest version of ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your routes file, you use `devise` for authentication and deny all the actions of `users_controller` except `show` :

`resources :users, :only => [:show]`

That means that **registration/edit** action is served by `Devise::RegistrationsController` (give it a look [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)). In case you want to perform some filtering for `edit` action, you should implement `before_action` inside of that particular `registrations_controller`. This can be achieved by a couple of ways:

1. Monkey-patching `devise` gem's source code. In this case you should find your gem's local folder and modify the corresponding `.rb` file (NOT RECOMMENDED).
2. Overriding `devise` default controller with your own and applying your `before_action` to `edit` of that overriden controller. Basically you can just create folder named `devise` in your controllers and copy/paste the entire devise controller into it. This requires no additional configuration. For more info on this topic you can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller) or even just watch through other topics here at Stack Overflow with "devise overriding" titles.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've followed the advice you linked and successfully overwritten the registration controller. Everything is now working as it should!