# customizing the devise gem controller in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[i have customize the devise gem controller in my application]

[error comes : uninitialized constant SessionsController]
 i also copies the view in to the separate section but still it comes

Comment: Here is the answer [Answer from StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.rb must be devise_for like this

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```