# Rails 4 Devise Call Back on Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two models

> User(id, name, is_host,....)
>
> Host(id, name, user_id,...)

With the Association

> User hasOne Host

I am using Devise for the User Registration. When a user wants to register as a Host i want to set `is_host = 1` and `create a row in Host` with the `name` of the Host he provides in the Registration Form.

What i want to do?

1. Allow Registration Form to accept Host details
2. Create the association data when user selects `register as host`

Am trying to figure where i can write the logic based on what the user chooses to register as and then create the associated row in Host.

User From

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <% f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <% f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :is_host %><br />
    <%= radio_button("user", "is_host", true) %> Yes
    <br/>
    <%= radio_button("user", "is_host", false) %> No
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Signup" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It would be good if you post the form code

Comment: I think this can help you, overriding devise controllers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller or a better answer given by @RSB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to add an `attr_accessor` to the user model, e.g.

```
attr_accessor :host_name
```

And use this in the form as

```
= f.text_field :host_name
```

You can add an `after_create` callback in the model to save the host based upon the value of the radio button

```
after_create :create_user_host, if: Proc.new { |user| user.is_host }

def create_user_host
  self.create_host(name: host_name)  
end
```

**or**

You can use https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form gem to save the association directly. Just add

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :host
```

and in the form

```
= nested_form_for resource do |f|
  # code for user
  = f.fields_for :host do |host_f|
    = host_f.text_field :name
```

More details can be found in [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Paji :) one more question. 'self.create_host(name: host_name) ' will this create a row in the 'hosts' table

Comment: Yes, it will create a host associated with the user

Comment: But dont we need to add something like Host.create(name: host_name)

Comment: No thats not required, `create_host` method is used because it has one to one relation with the user

Comment: Still if you want to create it using `create` than you can write this instead, `Host.create(name: host_name, user_id: self.id)`

Comment: wow. Rails magic :P one more thing. Is it possible for me to have two forms. One sign up for Users and One Sign up for Hosts. and submit to the same controller to let the above magic take charge?

Comment: You can surely do that, in the migration set `is_host` default to `false`. If there's a form where `host` fields are not present then `after_create` callback will not be executed we have added a condition there. As you can see, to implement the functionality I have written everything in model. You don't have to change anything in controller side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75776/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-rsb).