# How to call update action for another form?Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I trying to update devise user attributes from another controller.

here is form

```
= form_for @client, url: { action: 'update', controller: '/registrations'} , :html => { method: :patch } do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.text_field :phone
  = f.submit
```

but shell show me an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"registrations", :id=>"5"}
```

how fix it?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you overrided devise's registration_controller?

Comment: rake routes and check do you have this route?

Comment: You need to override update method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller. Refer this link

Comment: Could you add the contents of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: If you want access devise's registration_controller then you should write:
"form_for @client, url: { action: 'update', controller: 'devise/registrations'}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
= form_for @client, url: registration_path(:user), method: :put do |f|
```

**or**

```
= form_for @client, url: { action: 'update', controller: 'devise/registrations'}, method: :put do |f|
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I still get an error :) `No route matches [PUT] "/user/users/edit"`
I think, I will use a default form for edit attributes, thank you

Comment: Edited again, paste `rake routes` results if this doesn't work again