# Rails Automatically create 1:1 dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 app that uses Devise.

I'm trying to let the User model alone so that I don't cross paths with Devise, so I created a Profile model for all my settings/views the user will have.

The Profile has

```
belongs_to :user
```

The User has

```
has_one :profile
```

Where do I put the logic that the app needs to know to create a profile upon new user creation, and delete it upon user deletion?

Comment: I would go with an after_create callback as pointed out below, but there's really no reason to be afraid of [customizing your User model](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html). It's not that tough, and it's likely to save you trouble down the line.

Comment: would you know how to add in the user controller/views etc. if devise is already installed without messing up devise?

Comment: The controllers and views for User have little to do with Devise. Devise has  a registrations_controller.rb file, and a new user is created when a new Devise registration is created. You'd also be modifying app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb and so on. These modifications are beyond the scope of a comment, so please read the Devise doc, make some effort to try coding what you can and post follow up questions separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Active Record Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to create a profile. And you can use `dependent: :destroy` to make sure the profile will get destroyed when the user is destroyed.

In your `models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy # destroy user's profile

  after_create :create_default_profile

  ... ...

  private
    def create_default_profile
      Profile.create(user_id: self.id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails associations have a [`dependent` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent), which handles deleting associated records.

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependant: :destroy
end
```

- `:destroy`, when the object is destroyed, destroy will be called on its
  associated objects.
- `:delete`, when the object is destroyed, all its
  associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without
  calling their destroy method.

Creating the associated `Profile` can be done with [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) or in the controller. I have getting more and more weary of callbacks since its difficult to control when and where they are actually run.

In the case of Devise you would [override the `Devise::RegistrationsController`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller).

Comment: However, I would not add a bunch of complication just do avoid clashing with Devise. Devise does not add a huge amount of properties even with a bunch of modules activated. I would consider adding a `Users::Preference` model or something like it if you want to have a bunch of user prefs in your app.